# Bootstrap and visited links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

We are using Bootstrap to provide responsiveness for our sites. It is good UX practice to indicate followed links, but as Bootstrap was built for applications, it doesn't support this. Are there any workarounds that people have used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue was logged and closed with bootstrap over a year ago (see [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2144)) and indeed the workaround recommended is to just use a:visited

Comment: Thanks - the key comment is "We leave this up to developers. In applications, visited isn't useful and can actually be detrimental.". The problem is that Bootstrap is not just used for applications, and for websites, indicating visited links is best practice, e.g. http://www.nngroup.com/articles/change-the-color-of-visited-links/.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I use it for websites as well and think it's a great product, but if you forget the a:visited it can become confusing for visitors for sure.

Comment: I always thought it was odd that they should disable the visited links but if it was designed for applications then maybe that makes sense. Visited links should always be colored (preferably purple) - it is kind of like web development 101.