# How to unstyle anchor when using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap adds very nice default styles for anchors, but it makes it difficult to use `<a>` tag for something other than blue text. Say, I want the text to be black. One way to do that would be to add `class="my_class"` to the anchor tag, and then put `a.my_class{color:black}` rule.

But as I will soon realize bootstrap adds also style for `:hover`. So, I have to change that too. 
Also it changes styles for `outline`, `text-decoration`, `:focus`, etc.

Of course I could just read unminified version of bootstrap.css and try to understand what are all the cases I have to cover, to make sure it stays black.
But I perceive that there must be some easier way - I was expecting something like adding `class="link-unstyled"` or something?

Comment: you can overwrite all css you want to change.

Comment: You can not “remove” styles that are applied to an element via a rule, you can only overwrite them.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828829/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-get-rid-of-underlined-button-text-when-hovering-over-a

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/S9JXC/12/
You can style an individual element or a group of elements. In this case they override the styles defined by bootstrap.css which is loaded before these styles and take precedence.

**Styles defined by bootstrap.css**

```
a {
    color: #428BCA;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #2A6496;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Custom styles**

```
.style-1 {
    color: red;
}
.style-1:hover, 
.style:focus {
    color: darkred;
}
.style-2 a {
    color: #9F5F9F;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.style-2 a:hover,
.style-2 a:focus {
    color: #871F78;
}

<a href="#">Link</a><br>
<a href="#" class="style-1">Link with a different style</a>

<div class="style-2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. My problem is more general though: how do I know as a developer what I have to "unstyle". For example how do you know that you have to overwrite ":focus" but not ":visited"? I know the answer is "you can use grep on unminified bootstrap.css" but I was hoping that there is some documentation somewhere, or some simple trick like adding "link-unstyled" class (similary to list-unstyled).

Comment: Read this which you should know: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/link/ + http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/link/

Answer (score 49):

[Reset color](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#reset-color) `.text-reset` and [Text Decoration](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#text-decoration) `.text-decoration-none` are [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/) options for achieving this.

Comment: this should be the correct answer, simply adding 2 bootstrap built-in classes solve the problem!

Comment: That solution works with Bootstrap 5 as well.

Answer (score 48):

Even later to the party but with a shorter solution for for normal text links (inside `p` etc.):

```
.link-unstyled, .link-unstyled:link, .link-unstyled:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

<strike>My tests show that with `:link` all special styles on hover or after clicking it are removed.</strike>

**Edit 22.11.2015**: `:hover` is still needed for some use cases, for example in the following snippet. Updated the css above.

```css
.link-unstyled, .link-unstyled:link, .link-unstyled:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
.bg-menu:hover {
  background-color: #0079C1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" style="width:400px;">
  <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="link-unstyled">test1-1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="link-unstyled">test1-2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="link-unstyled">test1-3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="link-unstyled">test2-1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="link-unstyled">test2-2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="link-unstyled">test2-3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="link-unstyled">test3-1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="link-unstyled">test3-2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="bg-menu clickable"><a href="#" class="link-unstyled">test3-3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to me to be by far the best response around, and it works like a charm :)
Thanks for sharing the knowledge !

Comment: I use the above but find that adding   cursor: pointer; to the hover style provides a visual clue that it is, in fact, a link.

Comment: @marcp yeah, it depends on what `unstyle` means for you :-)

Comment: what about `cursor: default;`?

Answer (score 8):

Came across this and while Jeroen's answer is pretty comprehensive, it's also quite long.

If I want this label to have the normal label text color, I just need two new CSS rules.

```css
a.unlink {
  color: inherit;
}
a.unlink:hover {
  color: inherit;
}
```

If you look at my snippet, you can see the difference.

```css
a.unlink {
  color: inherit;
}
a.unlink:hover {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="label label-primary"><a class="unlink" href="#">Good looking tag</a></span> <-- This looks good
<br />
<span class="label label-primary"><a href="#">Bad looking tag</a></span> <-- This looks bad
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to the party, but would still like to offer an alternative answer to address some issues from the question directly, and offer my own solution FWIW.

### Some general points

> I was expecting something like adding `class="link-unstyled"` or something?

Me too. Apparently it isn't there.

> Of course I could just read unminified version of bootstrap.css [...] But I perceive that there must be some easier way.

Don't be too afraid: the twitter-bootstrap source is fairly understandable. Have a look at [the appropriate lines in scaffolding.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/scaffolding.less#L46), which look like this:

```css
// Links      

a { 
  color: @link-color; 
  text-decoration: none; 

  &:hover, 
  &:focus { 
    color: @link-hover-color; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
  } 

  &:focus { 
    .tab-focus(); 
  } 
}
```

So in fact, the Bootstrap source surprised me: as you mention there is at least also `:visited`, but Bootstrap ignores that. The answer to that is found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16541819/419956):

> as Bootstrap was built for applications, it doesn't support [`:visited`]

Makes sense. Anyways, I guess we only have to override the styles Bootstrap sets, adding other pseudo selectors as we desire. But, as you say in your comment on the other answer:

> how do I know as a developer what I have to "unstyle"?

There is in fact a short list of things you have to override, which [MDN summarizes in the :hover article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover):

> In order to style appropriately links, you need to put the :hover rule after the :link and :visited rules but before the :active one, as defined by the LVHA-order: :link — :visited — :hover — :active.

That's the answer to your question: you know from MDN (or if you must: from the W3 spec, which is of course 'more authorative') - or you know from looking at this Stack Overflow thread you've created :-).

If you wish, you can still set `:active` for your website though. Which brings me to...

### My solution

This is in fact the solution you allude to in your question: use a specific class to style the correct pseudo-classes.

**Sass version:**

```
$unstyledAColor: #333;
$unstyledAColorHover: #000;
$unstyledAColorInverse: #969696;
$unstyledAColorInverseHover: #FFF;

.a-unstyled {
    color: $unstyledAColor;
    &:link { color: $unstyledAColor; }
    &:visited { color: $unstyledAColor; }
    &:hover { color: $unstyledAColorHover; }
    &:active { color: $unstyledAColor; }
}

.navbar-inverse .a-unstyled {
    color: $unstyledAColorInverse;

    &:link { color: $unstyledAColorInverse; }
    &:visited { color: $unstyledAColorInverse; }
    &:hover { color: $unstyledAColorInverseHover; }
    &:active { color: $unstyledAColorInverse; }
}
```

**CSS version:**

```
.a-unstyled { color: #333; }
.a-unstyled:link { color: #333; }
.a-unstyled:visited { color: #333; }
.a-unstyled:hover { color: #000; }
.a-unstyled:active { color: #333; }

.navbar-inverse .a-unstyled { color: #969696; }
.navbar-inverse .a-unstyled:link { color: #969696; }
.navbar-inverse .a-unstyled:visited { color: #969696; }
.navbar-inverse .a-unstyled:hover { color: #FFF; }
.navbar-inverse .a-unstyled:active { color: #969696; }
```

Comment: +1 but the colors should be inherited (e.g. `color: inherit`) and you should add `text-decoration: none` as well

Answer (score 1):

I found a version for Bootstrap 3, just removed the visited property: [Bootstrap "link-unstyled" Helper Class](https://codepen.io/scottloway/pen/grgJgB)

```
.a-unstyled {
    &,
    &:link,
    &:visited,
    &:hover,
    &:active,
    &:active:hover {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
    /*font-style: inherit;
      background-color: transparent;
      font-size: inherit;
      font-variant: inherit;
      font-weight: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      border-radius: inherit;
      border: inherit;
      outline: inherit;
      box-shadow: inherit;
      padding: inherit;
      vertical-align: inherit;*/
    }
}
```

This includes the inheritance suggestion of @Ohad Schneider's comment.